Self-Organising Map (SOM) - Default Neighbourhood Radius of 66.6%
I've recently been using a self-organising map (SOM) as a preliminary stage of clustering.
When using the SOM, I've paid particular attention to different outcomes associated with setting the neighbourhood radius parameter at different values.
This made me curious on whether anyone knew of a theoretical source which supports claims that the default should be set at 66.6% of all unit-to-unit distances?
The 66.6% claim is made here by Rejeb et al. And also here by co-authors of the Kohonen package.
Both of which provide no clear motivation for the default value. Therefore, if anyone knew of a source for the 66.6% justification, this would be greatly appreciated.
